# How to write nested dictionary in Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary

So i have this json:

```
"transactions": [
        {
            "balance": "15000",
            "description": "Makan di indomaret",
            "date": "09-01-2019",
            "week": "1"
        },
        {
            "balance": "25000",
            "description": "Makan di alfamart",
            "date": "08-01-2019",
            "week": "1"
        }
    ]
```

And i wonder to write this json structure with dictionary.
here the code

```
var jsonData = [String : [[String : Any]]]()
```

Thank you.

Comment: please, can you be more clearly what you want to achive?

Comment: The JSON is in fact `[String: [[String: Any]]]`, it's a Dictionary with one value where its value is an Array of Dictionary, you are missing a level. Plus from where is coming the "Int" key in your `jsonData`? That's unclear.

Comment: `var jsonData = [String : [[String : Any]]]()`

Comment: Read up on  `Codable` for easy to use built-in json handling in Swift.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

then you can make a loop to make a dictionary that later will be appended to arrayDictionary

`let array = [[String:Any]]()`

```
for item in data {
 let dictionary = [String:Any]()
 dictionary["object1"] = item.id
 dictionary["object2"] = item.name
 dictionary["object3"] = item.address

 array.append(dictionary)
}
```

Comment: "then you can make...", this suggest something has already happened. Can you explain what, maybe there is just a sentence missing, because I am having a hard time connecting this answer to the question

Comment: a dictionary or an array declared as constant will be empty for ever

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
var jsonData = [String : [String : Any]]()
```

because the key ("transactions") is String and its value (

```
[{
    "balance": "15000",
    "description": "Makan di indomaret",
    "date": "09-01-2019",
    "week": "1"
},
{
    "balance": "25000",
    "description": "Makan di alfamart",
    "date": "08-01-2019",
    "week": "1"
}]
```

is a array of string : any